# Can't figure out why root-relative link will not work

Tags: php, html, apache, directory, xampp

I'm working on making my web app more portable but I'm having trouble with making links in a sub-directory root-relative.

> /website - Let's say that's my directory for the website.
>  /inc -
>   That's my includes directory for header, footer, and eventually my
>   config file.

Everything inside the website directory works fine.

I'm trying to include my header/footer files in a receipt directory with..

`include("/website/inc/header.php");`

but I get..

> Warning: include(/website/inc/header.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in F:\xampp\htdocs\website\receipt\index.php on
>   line 8
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/website/inc/header.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.;F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\website\receipt\index.php on line 8

in my browser. I've tried removing the **/** and even adding **localhost** and `htdocs` (which was just a desperate attempt at getting it to work). What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because a file path starting with `/` is treated as a file path starting from the root of file system. You have `F:\` as a root that's why such a directory doesn't exist.

In your case you have to do something like `../../website/inc/header.php` but that depends on the location of the folder where your script resists.

PHP (*but not HTML!*) works with whole file system, while HTML works only with the site's home directory.

By the way, such file paths are not allowed  on Windows, they're only available on UNIX-like systems. If such a construction with `/`'s works on your server, that's strange as Windows has `\` as path separator. Your code'll look like `..\..\website\inc\header.php`. Note that you may need to escape the backslashes by adding another backslash like this `\\`

Comment: PHP on Windows will work with "/" as readily as it will work with "\"

Comment: When you say "root of file system" does that mean my `htdocs` directory or `F:` ?

Comment: @Atonium, please read carefully, I've mentioned that F:// is the root

Comment: @Atonium - root of the filesystem is from "F:\"

Comment: @ForceBru Missed that, sorry.

Comment: @Atonium, please correct the slashes in your question and make them _backslashes_.

Comment: @ForceBru, Thank you for the help. By adding the path from root to my website, it is now corrected. I was under the impression PHP interpreted `/` as my htdocs directory. As @Mark Baker said, both `/` and \  work on windows apparently. When I `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, it displays the path with forwardslashes. Wish I could upvote the answer; not enough rep.

Comment: It's not a URI at all, it's a file path, and `/` works fine on Windows when you aren't passing it to an external program.

Comment: @Quentin, yeah, a file path, certainly, just forgot that word and used this. Thanks. Gonna correct it.